# How to make exact decimal computations?

Tags: dart

I need to make decimal computations but sometimes the result is not exact.

```dart
0.009 + 0.001; // => 0.009999999999999998
```

How can I workaround that ?

Comment: why don't dart doubles, by default, work that expression out correctly? whats so hard about 0.009 + 0.001 they are both finite precision rational numbers well within the double types precision.

Comment: `double` is a 64-bit (double-precision) floating-point number, as specified by the [IEEE 754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) standard. Regarding this definition the result is correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [decimal package](http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/decimal). This package enables to make computations on decimal numbers without loosing precision like double operations.

```dart
Decimal.parse('0.2') + Decimal.parse('0.1'); // => 0.3
```

`Decimal.parse('0.2')` returns a new `Decimal` object that can be handled like `num` (by the way `Decimal` is not a `num` because `num` cannot be used as superclass or implemented).

To make your code shorter you can define a shortcut for `Decimal.parse` :

```dart
final d = Decimal.parse;
d('0.2') + d('0.1'); // => 0.3
```

Comment: Can you explain shortly what approach you took to solve the problem? Just to get the idea.

Comment: The decimal package is implemented upon the [rational package](http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/rational). Every decimal can be seen as a fraction of 2 ints. As Dart provides unlimited integer it is quite simple to implement it. The only problem was with dart2js because it doesn't follow the spec on unlimited int. To workaround I have implemented my own version of [bigint](https://github.com/a14n/dart-rational/blob/master/lib/bigint.dart).

Comment: @alexandre-ardhuin I installed your package, imported the file, but it says no such method `dec()`. I also checked the source of the package and haven't found a method with such name. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Ooops, sorry, I forgot I replaced the `dec` top-level function by `Decimal.parse` to be closer to the double API. Answer updated.